# Songs like "Father and Son" by Cat Stevens

Tags: identify-this-genre, songwriter

I heard this song "Father & Son" by Cat Stevens. I really liked it. I liked this fact that Cat used a deeper register for the father while a higher one for the son. What is the genre of this song or what type of song is this called, with a mix of deeper and higher registers like this? How can I find other songs like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a genre, because Stevens uses the two registers for a very specific reason based on the lyrics --he's playing two different characters, one older and one younger.  The only other songs I can think of that do characters by register are the middle section of Queen's ["Bohemian Rhapsody,"](https://youtu.be/fJ9rUzIMcZQ?t=3m9s), and the goofy call-and-response section of Justin Timberlake's [Senorita](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJHYDkvRB2Y?t=m3s20) which are both very different songs.  Billy Joel plays two different characters in "[Still Rock and Roll to Me,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eAQa4MOGkE)" but they are in the same register.

There are duets, [usually between male and female singers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UVNT4wvIGY), that have a similar effect, but those don't necessarily cluster in any one genre.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the type of thing you're after
https://youtu.be/R9IWAxSpgKA

Comment: Sorry I wanted to ask for mp3.

Comment: My apologies. I forgot about the mp3 request